# Git Bash Missing Branch Name and $ in line

Tags: git, git-bash

I am having a weird issue with git bash. I just installed git and whenever I open git bash in my local repository, the branch name is missing and the $ symbol before each line is also missing:

[image]

The image above shows my issue. That directory is already the local repository yet it is not showing the branch name beside it and the line does not start with the $ symbol.

My `PS1` is set to:

```
[\e]0;\w\a]\n[\e[32m]\u@\h [\e[35m]$MSYSTEM[\e[0m] [\e[33m]\w[\e[0m]\n
```

I can still do git commands but I am not really comfortable with this.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see when you execute `echo $PS1`?

Comment: @paxdiablo here: \[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n

Comment: I don't see anything there that would cause it to display git information or a `$` symbol. jngacayan, what led you to expect that your prompt would show the branch name in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous versions of Git Bash had a different `$PS1` which included branch information and the dollar sign. The default `$PS1` that includes the dollar sign is below:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

Instructions for adding the branch name can be found from [this file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) in the official Git development repository.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PS1` variable has neither a `$(__git_ps1)` nor a closing `$` in it. The former is what gives you the branch name, the latter will give you your `$` at the end.

For example, this one is what I have set:

```
\[\e]0;git__${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u \[\e[33m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\]\n>
```

For your *particular* needs, you may want to look at starting with:

```
PS1='\e]0;\w\n\e[32m\u@\h \e[35m$MSYSTEM\e[0m \e[33m\w\e[0m$(__git_ps1)\n$ '
```

and working from there. That gives me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought that is the normal behavior since i did install git before on different machines and all of them have this behavior. So that is no longer the default config for git for the latest version?